# Best way to have i18n autocompletetextview

Tags: android

AutoCompleteTextView works great with a string array defined in your resources. However if you use the standard example for the countries list as seen on the android developer site the list will be different for each locale.

Assume you would have to display the i18n country names but under the hood you have to track the ISO country code. So the autocompletion has to be country specific (locale) and list sorted correctly.

At the moment I am hauling up list collections of a of Country pojos with isocode and description attributes for the locale. For the autocompletelist I use the descriptions in their own array and then when needing the isocode I do a reverse lookup in the collection.

There gotta be a better pattern for this sort of thing though. Similar use case it around spinners. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Adapter doesn't have to return a list of strings. If you have a list collection of Country pojos, just have the adapter use it (ListAdapter for instance). You may want to do your own implementation of filtering or have Country.toString() return something suitable for sorting.

Comment: so the country pojo toString method should return the i18n version of the country read from the resources? And that would work for the autocompletion, but I would still have access to the code in the pojo? There is nothing like a string-array with a key for each item is there?

Comment: Maybe .. e.g. for the country example with the ISO code something like this would be awesome. <string-array name="countries"><item name="AT">Austria</item></string-array> and so on. At the moment I just have a whole bunch of normal strings in resources that I tie together to a map in code.. and yes. You could call it a string-map ;-)

Comment: Thanks Romain. I tried that now and it works. Not ideal but ok.